# tomcat can not find maven dependencies

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat6, maven-plugin

A few hours ago I was working on my web application and it was working alright. But somehow a rather strange problem has started occurring and I am getting the following error:

```
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springatwork' did not find a matching property.
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\csvn\bin\;C:\csvn\Python25\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\Home\apache-tomcat\bin;C:\Home\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Home\apache-ant\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 455 ms
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:583)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/springatwork] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
Nov 7, 2011 1:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 328 ms
```

I am using m2 maven plugin with eclipse and the project is maven webapp. The project works alright when I use the **tomcat-maven-plugin** but if I try to deploy it to the configured tomcat server in my Eclipse 3.5 IDE then I get the above error.

**EDIT**: Also, when I stop the tomcat I get the following at the end:

```
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

Only thing I remember doing was trying to do some debugging using debugging mode.

Could someone help me understand why is it happening and how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried closing/restarting eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I tried that a few times. I even tried restarting my computer but none of that helped. I've edited the question with some extra information.

Comment: I dont know how and why but after deleting the project from Eclipse IDE and then importing back again it started working. But for some reasons I can't work with Eclipse debugger properly. I wonder if it has anything to do with `-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javaw.exe` that I added in `eclipse.ini` to get around the maven plugin problem. `Use Step Filters` while working in debug mode doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have something like this in your Project properties -> Deployment Assembly:
[ Maven Dependencies :: WEB-INF/lib ]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an m2eclipse-wtp bug, which is the eclipse plugin that is supposed to import the maven war configuration and create the eclipse project from, including which libraries should be compile-time and which ones should be in the WEB-INF/lib. Different versions in the past have given me problems for years. I always had to manually fix these in the eclipse project settings. Different versions of eclipse set this in different places, so that doesn't make it any easier.

Comment: In my case after having `-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javaw.exe` the problem was solved but tomcat not being able to pick maven dependencies all of the sudden was rather strange. I wonder why did that happen?